# I got the message: "Bad import syntax:" when I try to import a python function inside my gnuradio flowgraph

Tags: python, function, import, gnuradio

I'm trying to do this tutorial on gnuradio page:
https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/TutorialPythonFunctions

It looks to be simple but I got the message "bad import syntax" when I try  to import my function "testpy".

Has someone had the same problem or knows how to solve it?

[image]

Comment: can you write your code example with python import?

Comment: All the code is auto generated with gr_modtool script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately cryptic. What you have to write in the box is a [Python import statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement),

 not just the name of the module to import. That is, write

```
import testpy
```

instead of just `testpy`.

You can also use `from <module> import <name>, <name>` and all the other forms of the `import` statement. (That's why it wants the statement and not just module names: so you can do either kind of import.)